# Copying skin weights+vertex paint+bindskin+rigging+reducing polycount+bindskin in ver. 1.8 blender

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights, vertex-paint, polycount

So I've created two models of equal sizes and shapes in blender 1.8 and would like to do the following tasks on one of the models:

1. Copy skin weights from one model to another
2. Add vertex paint to some parts of the first model
3. Add the option "bindskin"(I used Maya before)
4. Reduce polycount without losing details
5. Rigging the ponytail of the hair of the model

Now I'm facing the following problems:

1. I'm not getting options to copy skin weights in blender
2. I tried my best to apply vertex paint but the paintbrush is simply not painting anything, not even an edge
3. "Bindskin" Option isn't present in blender
4. I used decimate modifier to reduce polycount but in that case the hair of the model looks like polygons glued together
5. I'm failing to make one of the bones the parent of the other. Is there a shortcut key for this?
   I used drag+shift+drop in this case

What can I do to avert these problems? I'm intermediate in blender

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using Blender 2.8 or 1.8?

Comment: This is too many questions at once.  I've voted to close on the basis of "needs focus."

Comment: Please split your question list into separate question posts. This site is a question-and-answer site that works differently than a forum. It's one question & one or more answers. If you ask 5 questions at once you can get 25 different answers - which is a total mess for other readers that are looking for specific answers for their similar questions.